# Avoid indented lines in footnote

Tags: footnotes, layout, tablenotes

I have a small problem with a longer text in a footnote. With a long text and multiple lines, every new line is indented.
How can I avoid this irregularity?

Here is a short example:

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=11pt,
paper=a4,
DIV=10,
BCOR=8mm,
oneside,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Test for the tnote in a threeparttable}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    A & B \\
    \midrule
    1234 & 2\tnote{a} \\
    3234 & 4 \\
    5234 & 6\tnote{b} \\
    7234 & 8 \\
    9234 & 10\tnote{c} \\
    11234 & 12 \\
    13234 & 14\tnote{d} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[a]\scriptsize{Test for number 2.}
    \item[b]\scriptsize{Test for number 6.}
    \item[c]\scriptsize{Test for number 10.}
    \item[d]\scriptsize{Test for number 14.}
     \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}

   And now there is also a new sentence with a footnote\footnote{\blindtext}  that looks strange at the end of the page because there is a missing gap?
    \end{document}
```

BTW: Why does the letter a looks bigger than the letters b, c and d in the tablenotes of the threeparttable? How can I fix that?

Comment: Sorry, indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the KOMA script manual, the footnotes behave as intended: [image: koma script manual screenshot]

It seems to be a regular `\parindent`.

The package `\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. That's it. Now it looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `[flushleft]` option for `threeparttable`. Also replace `caption` with `\captionabove` to have a decent spacing between caption and table. Last, `\scriptizesize` can be  set once and for all just after entering the `tablenotes` environment.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, DIV=10, BCOR=8mm, oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{table}
\centering
\captionabove{Test for the tnote in a threeparttable}
 \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    A & B \\
    \midrule
    1234 & 2\tnote{a} \\
    3234 & 4 \\
    5234 & 6\tnote{b} \\
    7234 & 8 \\
    9234 & 10\tnote{c} \\
    11234 & 12 \\
    13234 & 14\tnote{d} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}\scriptsize
    \item[a]Test for number 2.
    \item[b]Test for number 6.
    \item[c]Test for number 10.
    \item[d]Test for number 14.
    \end{tablenotes}
 \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for all the corrections and tips. All letters look similar in size now.

Answer (score 0):

It is a design decision but you can change it. Btw: \scriptsize doesn't take an argument, it is a switch.

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=11pt,
paper=a4,
DIV=10,
BCOR=8mm,
oneside,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\deffootnote[1.5em]{1.5em}{1.5em}{%
\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}%
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Test for the tnote in a threeparttable}
\begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    A & B \\
    \midrule
    1234 & 2\tnote{a} \\
    3234 & 4 \\
    5234 & 6\tnote{b} \\
    7234 & 8 \\
    9234 & 10\tnote{c} \\
    11234 & 12 \\
    13234 & 14\tnote{d} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}\scriptsize
    \item[a] Test for number 2.
    \item[b]Test for number 6.
    \item[c]Test for number 10.
    \item[d]Test for number 14.
     \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}

   And now there is also a new sentence with a footnote\footnote{\blindtext}  that looks strange at the end of the page because there is a missing gap?
    \end{document}
```